# Spring Security Core and mongoDB Doesn't Authenticate

Tags: mongodb, grails, spring-security

I created this project using Grails 2.3.3 and added mongoDB GORM Plugin and Spring Security Core plugin to it. I followed this post [spring-security-and-mongodb](http://etcpe9.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/grails-application-with-spring-security-and-mongodb/) to make it work, I can see the user and role in mongodb collection, but when I enter username and password the application doesn't authenticate against it, or maybe there is something broken somewhere that says the authentication failed. I attached the project zip file here, can someone look at it and see if I mis-configured something that makes it not-working.

[ProjectZipFile](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/file/n4652087/mongoSecurity.zip)

Answer (score 4):

I used your attached application and the blog post you referenced to create a working application. See http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1992 for usage information and https://github.com/burtbeckwith/mongoSpringSecurity for the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your BootStrap.groovy file you are saving Role and User objects but you also need to create an association between User and Role using UserRole object.

Comment: But I have the Authority embedded in user, right ? Can you explain how to do that ? Maybe paste the code you have in mind. Thanks

Comment: I added the following code but it still doesn't authenticate. Did you manage to make it work ?  "UserRole.create user, userRole, true"

Comment: I tried the code you have in your github the mongoDB Blog, it has the same problem. Do you have a simple project that uses Spring Security and MongoDB at the same time and works ?

Comment: Blog code that I have on github is running fine on heroku, you can clone the code in your local machine and try out. By the way as Burt mentioned above version 2 of Spring Security address issues which makes it work out of the box with MongoDB.